# Select all of the objects in one line of code

Tags: excel, vba

Is there a good way to simplify this? Possibly by selecting the whole array of objects in one line?

```
Sub GiveAllBulletsCellsValueOfOne()
  '' there are 15 bullets, sorry I accidentally skipped 3 when naming the shapes in excel.
    ''I would like to select all the bullets at once rather than a separate line of code for each bullet. 

          Range(ActiveSheet.Shapes("bullet 1").TopLeftCell.Address & ":" & ActiveSheet.Shapes("bullet 1").BottomRightCell.Address).Value = 1
          Range(ActiveSheet.Shapes("bullet 2").TopLeftCell.Address & ":" & ActiveSheet.Shapes("bullet 2").BottomRightCell.Address).Value = 1
          Range(ActiveSheet.Shapes("bullet 4").TopLeftCell.Address & ":" & ActiveSheet.Shapes("bullet 4").BottomRightCell.Address).Value = 1
          Range(ActiveSheet.Shapes("bullet 5").TopLeftCell.Address & ":" & ActiveSheet.Shapes("bullet 5").BottomRightCell.Address).Value = 1
          Range(ActiveSheet.Shapes("bullet 6").TopLeftCell.Address & ":" & ActiveSheet.Shapes("bullet 6").BottomRightCell.Address).Value = 1
          Range(ActiveSheet.Shapes("bullet 7").TopLeftCell.Address & ":" & ActiveSheet.Shapes("bullet 7").BottomRightCell.Address).Value = 1
          Range(ActiveSheet.Shapes("bullet 8").TopLeftCell.Address & ":" & ActiveSheet.Shapes("bullet 8").BottomRightCell.Address).Value = 1
          Range(ActiveSheet.Shapes("bullet 9").TopLeftCell.Address & ":" & ActiveSheet.Shapes("bullet 9").BottomRightCell.Address).Value = 1
          Range(ActiveSheet.Shapes("bullet 10").TopLeftCell.Address & ":" & ActiveSheet.Shapes("bullet 10").BottomRightCell.Address).Value = 1
          Range(ActiveSheet.Shapes("bullet 11").TopLeftCell.Address & ":" & ActiveSheet.Shapes("bullet 11").BottomRightCell.Address).Value = 1
          Range(ActiveSheet.Shapes("bullet 12").TopLeftCell.Address & ":" & ActiveSheet.Shapes("bullet 12").BottomRightCell.Address).Value = 1
          Range(ActiveSheet.Shapes("bullet 13").TopLeftCell.Address & ":" & ActiveSheet.Shapes("bullet 13").BottomRightCell.Address).Value = 1
          Range(ActiveSheet.Shapes("bullet 14").TopLeftCell.Address & ":" & ActiveSheet.Shapes("bullet 14").BottomRightCell.Address).Value = 1
          Range(ActiveSheet.Shapes("bullet 15").TopLeftCell.Address & ":" & ActiveSheet.Shapes("bullet 15").BottomRightCell.Address).Value = 1
          Range(ActiveSheet.Shapes("bullet 16").TopLeftCell.Address & ":" & ActiveSheet.Shapes("bullet 16").BottomRightCell.Address).Value = 1
 End Sub()
```

Comment: Did you try to do it in the loop, code for every shape is the same.

Comment: You say "select" but that's not what your code is doing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Dim n As Long

With ActiveSheet
    For n = 1 To 16
        If n <> 3 Then
            .Range(.Shapes("bullet " & n).TopLeftCell, _
                   .Shapes("bullet " & n).BottomRightCell).Value = 1
        End If
    Next n
End With
```

Answer (score 0):

### A Thorn in Your Side (Shapes, Controls)

- The following might solve your problem with the missing shape name
  (`bullet 3`), while the actual answer has already been provided.
- It is best run from VBE <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F11</kbd> using the
  Immediate window <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd>.
- Start with the first two `Sub`s which are harmless. Be extremely
  careful with the third. The fourth is just a byproduct while
  investigating your issue.
- If "bullet" is a name you made up then the third `Sub` should rename
  the shapes with indexes from `1` to `15`. If this works, then you
  will have to change `16` to `15` and remove the `If` (don't forget
  `End If`) statement from the solution provided by Tim Williams.

**The Code**

```
Option Explicit

' Lists all shapes in the Immediate window (CTRL+G).
Sub listShapes()
    Dim shp As Shape, n As Long
    n = 1
    For Each shp In ActiveSheet.Shapes
        Debug.Print n, shp.Name
        n = n + 1
    Next shp
End Sub

' Lists only the shapes with names that start with a specified name.
Sub listShapesGeneric()
    Const Gen As String = "bullet"
    Dim shp As Shape, n As Long
    n = 1
    For Each shp In ActiveSheet.Shapes
        If StrComp(Left(shp.Name, Len(Gen)), Gen, 1) = 0 Then
            Debug.Print n, shp.Name
            n = n + 1
        End If
    Next shp
End Sub

' Renames shapes with the name "oldGen", adding "Delimiter" and an incremented
' number starting from "oldLastIndex + 1". Then again loops through the shapes
' and renames them using "newGen", adding "Delimiter" and an incremented
' number starting with "NewFirstIndex".
' Best not used with system generic names if any control has been deleted
' e.g. "Button 1", when it could rename only a few controls.
' Therefore best use it with a made-up name.
Sub renameShapes()
    
    Const oldGen As String = "bullet"
    Const newGen As String = "bullet"
    Const Delimiter As String = " "
    Const oldLastIndex As Long = 50
    Const NewFirstIndex As Long = 1
    
    Dim shp As Shape, n As Long
    
    n = oldLastIndex: Debug.Print "Old"
    For Each shp In ActiveSheet.Shapes
        If StrComp(Left(shp.Name, Len(oldGen)), oldGen, 1) = 0 Then
            GoSub writeName
        End If
    Next shp
    
    n = NewFirstIndex - 1: Debug.Print "New"
    For Each shp In ActiveSheet.Shapes
        If StrComp(Left(shp.Name, Len(oldGen)), newGen, 1) = 0 Then
            GoSub writeName
        End If
    Next shp

    Exit Sub

writeName:
    n = n + 1
    shp.Name = newGen & Delimiter & n
    Debug.Print n, shp.Name
    Return

End Sub

' Adds a specified number of buttons starting from a specified cell
' in a worksheet. At the same time writes various properties of the buttons
' to the Immediate window (CTRL+G). Interestingly, the BottomRightCell
' for TopLeftCell "A1" is showing "B2" or "Offset(1,1 )".
Sub addButtons()
    
    Const NumberOfButtons As Long = 10
    Const FirstCellAddress As String = "A1"
    
    Dim cel As Range, btn As Button, i As Long
    
    For i = 1 To NumberOfButtons
        With ActiveSheet
            Set cel = .Range(FirstCellAddress)
            With cel
                Set btn = .Worksheet.Buttons.Add(.Left, .Top, .Width, .Height)
                With btn
                    Debug.Print .Name, .Text, .TopLeftCell.Address, _
                                .BottomRightCell.Address
                End With
            End With
        End With
    Next i

End Sub
```